# codeigniter and laravel frameworks

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

[image]I have been working with CodeIgniter since a month, now I have work on Laravel. I am bit confused that why we need Laravel when we are good with CodeIgniter. Why is Laravel preferred over CodeIgniter and what are the benefits that we get with Laravel?

[image: IMG]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We can't rate the value of Laravel 4 unless we understand some advanced OOP terminology. But I want to state that Laravel 4 is the most prominent framework to date for its some cool OOP Architecture. And now it's the best one as you can scale it in any sense, as long as you adhere to best coding ethics. Service Locator, IoC, Repository, Facade, Factory, Builder even Singleton is used here which is awesome. It's not so fast but better coding and better use of queue, cache can make it faster.

On the other hands, Codeigniter is not so scalable for its CI God object. But in OOP we can do many things possible with better structure of our App.

Comment: tanq u Anshul,how can i create a table in db by using laravel because i am familiar with codeigniter and i dont know where to put database names etc in laravel..could you please help me?

Comment: can you please tell me path in local host i.e url(ex:localhost/laravel/index.php/welcome/getstudents) for testing.

Comment: app/config/database.php or you can search in your IDE database.php in laravel folder.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them have its own specialties. 
But Laravel 4 depends a lot of a number of external packages for its functionality. To do this, it is **using Composer as a dependency manager**.

Comment: CI3 uses composer as well.

Comment: @Tpojka But CI3 doesnt support namespaces by default.. which majority of the third party libraries now use

Comment: You are right for namespaces, but one can use composer and packages in CI3 as well. Just need to be enabled in [config file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L123).

Answer (score 2):

I have also shifted from Codeigniter to Laravel. The things i like most in Laravel over Codeigniter are:

1. Built in authentication
2. Awesome migrations
3. Artisan commands to do anything in your project
4. Built in pagination (It's took long in Codeigniter)
5. Eloquent (Very easy way to interact with your database)
6. Relationships (Its make my life easy because i hate joins)
7. Routes
8. Easy API building
9. Easy debugging
10. Huge number of packages and libraries

and a lot more. I can make a more longer list.

Comment: I have a question - i got aware of laravel+voyager and it seems to be a good choice to have as pre-built boilerplate project so i can build my projects - with an existing admin panel. 
Question: is voyager a good fit to use for custom programming - like in codeigniter. What bothers me is the BREAD functionality - i don't think one has to implement all of your controller/models with these generators?! All in all - is laravel a good choice for converting my codeigniter project so that i have pre built admin area with access control and login etc. @umarbilal

Comment: Yes. Voyager is fully customizable  admin area. According to Voyager docs you have full control on what your application will do and how it will function. https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/getting-started/what-is-voyager#what-it-isnt

Comment: A second choice can be Python framework Django which also provides a built in admin panel. You can choose it if you are easy with python. https://www.djangoproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

Both framework are good in there place. Laravel used multiple open source technology to make laravel more efficient and reliable.
Eg.
For view : laravel used blade template engine.
Laravel used composer as a package manager.
Laravel used psr-4 .
Both framework follow MVC model.
Laravel provide more secure platform.